# C# .net and CLR Stored Procedures Question

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, clr

Are normal operations like:

DELETE From Product where ProductId = x faster in CLR then normal MS SQL 2005 Server Stored Procedures?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you measuring overall time (including AppDomain warmup), or just once everything has been loaded (e.g. execution plan in the SP version)?

Comment: I am trying to optimize stored procedures, so they execute faster and less taxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The general recommendation is to continue to use T-SQL for set based operations, and only consider using CLR for compute-bound tasks (or tasks for which there is no T-SQL equivalent).

See, for example, this MS [white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  While the difference may be so minute you would never be able to tell a stored procedure written in native T-SQL is going to be faster than one written in C# that has to be compiled into MSIL to run.

You should only do CLR stored procedures if you can't feasibly do something using native T-SQL.  For instance I have a CLR procedure that works with EDI and I have to do a large amount of text processing and that is not very feasible using T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Actually its faster to use stored procedure, since not every statement is recompiled on each use.